# SQL- How can I find the type for which maximum suicide cases have been registered for each state?

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

[image: Table structure]

For example I want my query to return ANDAMAN and Nicobar || By Hanging || 1332.

That is For each state the type for which maximum number of suicides registered.
It would be really helpful if anyone could help me with the query to achieve the same

Answer (score 1):

In MS-Access, I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable as t
where t.total_suicide = (
    select max(t1.total_suicide)
    from mytable as t1
    where t1.state = t.state
)
```

Comment: Access gets hanged each time I try to use aliases

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*,
       Row_number() over (partition by state order by total_suicide desc) as rn
  From your_table t) t
 Where rn = 1
```

Comment: this is an Access database - is `Row_number` available in Access?

Comment: I will try it once. if this works. Is there any other way to achieve this